# How to avoid BeautifulSoup warning in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am making a discord bot of my own and i have added wikipedia module in it . But when i am running the program and the calling the code i gives ma a warning which i tried to resolve but i am unable to do it . Please anyone help me to get rid of this problem. Also , it only runs on first attempt not another  The warning is as follows as :

I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 389 of the file C:\Users\upadh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

lis = BeautifulSoup(html).find_all('li')

Comment: The solution to the warning is in the warning message itself, it requires you to add the `features="html.parser"` to the `BeautifulSoup()` function like this -> `BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser"`

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing in your code:-

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
```

instead of doing that, do this:-

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, features="html.parser")
```